# Remove exact rows and frequency of rows of a data.frame where certain column values match with column values of another data.frame in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following two data.frames created using pandas in python 3:

```
a1 = pd.DataFrame(({'NO': ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6', 'd7', 'd8'],
                'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2], 
                'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'd', 'b']}))
a2 = pd.DataFrame(({'NO': ['d9', 'd10', 'd11', 'd12'],
                'A': [1, 2, 3, 2], 
                'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']}))
```

I would like to remove the exact rows of a1 that are in a2 wherever the values of columns 'A' an 'B' are the same (except for the 'NO' column) so that the result should be:

```
A B NO
4 d d4
5 e d5
4 d d7
2 b d8
```

Is there any built-in function in pandas or any other library in python 3 to get this result?

Comment: Asking again ? ...

Comment: Yes. I tried to modify your answer in order to accommodate a new column 'NO' (please see my post above), but did not succeed.

Comment: try the index remove method provided by others

Comment: It is working! Thanks.